# Mysql "insert select" gives me an "used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger" error

Tags: mysql

When I run that sql

```
insert into usersHistoryEvents(date,str,type, userid) 
(select now(),'hello', 'test', users.userId from gamesvidUsers, users
 WHERE gamesvidUsers.userid=users.userId and paid=1)
```

I got that error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you calling that code in an `UPDATE` function?

Comment: I would say, that there is some trigger on usersHistoryEvents and it is trying to update table users